# Azure kubernetes clusterrolebindings not working

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have an azure kubernetes cluster, setup with authentication and authorization set to "azure AD authentication with Kubernetes Rbac".
I expect to be able to use both AAD to authenticate, but also use regular service accounts within the cluster.

While it seems to work within my namespace, it looks as if i cannot grant service accounts access to cluster scoped ressources :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dummy-admin
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to
# read secrets in any namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: exmple-binding
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: dummy-admin  # Name is case sensitive
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: example-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: example-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kubectl
spec:
  serviceAccountName: dummy-admin
  containers:
  - name: kubectl
    image: bitnami/kubectl
   # Just spin & wait forever
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

Applying this config, and running `kubectl exec -ti pod/kubectl -- /bin/bash` and trying to list nodes, give me this error:

```
I have no name!@kubectl:/$ kubectl get all
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "replicationcontrollers" in API group "" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): daemonsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "daemonsets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): replicasets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "replicasets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "statefulsets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "horizontalpodautoscalers" in API group "autoscaling" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "jaiv"
Error from server (Forbidden): jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:jaiv:dummy-admin" cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "jaiv"
```

In this case, I see I am the correct identity, and would expect to be allowed to list resources in my namespace.

Comment: You shall read this : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole

Comment: @will this does not solve my issue, neither cluster role bindings or namespace scoped role bindings work.
I tried to create a clusterrole allowing `kubectl get nodes` and did a clusterrolebinding, and still get access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my mistake.

When doing the rolebinding, there are three different subject types: User, Group & ServiceAccount.
I was using User as a subject kind, and instead needed to define the rolebinding as:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This cluster role binding allows anyone in the "manager" group to
# read secrets in any namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: exmple-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: dummy-admin  # Name is case sensitive
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: example-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `role` and `rolebindings` instead of `clusterroles` and `clusterrolebdingins`. Those are differents resources type.

You are creating a service account in the `default` namespace and try to do something on the `jaiv` namespace. Try to instead use a `ClusterRole` and a `ClusterRoleBinding`. It also works for namepaced resources but clusterwide. (It is created identically, just has a different name)

More details here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole

Comment: All is deployed in my jaiv namespace, as that is where my context is set :)

The same happens with clusterrolebindings, neither works in my setup for some reason

Comment: ahh okay good to know. What I also see is that you use ```apiGroups: ["*"]``` instead of ```apiGroups [""]``` could you try this out?

Comment: or like to try list all apiGroups instead of "*"  like "apps","","batch","horizontalpodautoscaler"

Comment: After A quick research I found no example for apiGroup: "*". From where do you  have this?

Comment: Hmm, it seems changing to [""] had no effect.
As i can use * for verbs etc, i assumed it could also be used for the API's, though i also tried with specific api's while debugging

Comment: Ah, i see the apigroup: "*" is what i use for the role i give to azure AD users, so i can do a role binding for "USER@domain.com" .
This provides me with admin access for user authenticating with azure cli.
So my guess is it mathces all, same as the verbs etc